# Batch to include 'space' after "delims"

Tags: batch-file

Here is my batch line:

```
For /F "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%i in (list.txt) do echo %%i%%j
```

what contain list.text:

```
C:\Document and Setting\My Folder
```

above line shows: `C\Document`

but what I actually want: `C\Document and Setting\My Folder`

the issue is that after `"delims=:"` won't grab 'Space', I can user `"delims="` to grab space, but I don't want `':'` in the string.

any idea?

Comment: Well, you defined the colon and the space as delimiters...

Comment: actually, I find out just using Quotes(" ") will solve the problem       
                    
(For /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%i in (list.txt) do echo "%%i%%j")

Comment: No, because the quotes are then part of the output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
For /F "tokens=* delims=" %%i in (list.txt) do (
    set "drive=%%~di"
    echo !drive:~0,1!%%~pi%%~ni
)
```

here you can see how the arguments/tokens are expanded -> https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

Answer (score 3):

You are telling the `for` command to split by `:` and space because of the tokens you use. Split the string into 2 delimiting by `:` and use `tokens=1*` to assign everthing before `:` to `%%i` metavariable and the remaining to `%%j`, spaces included.:

```
@For /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%i in (list.txt) do echo %%i%%j
```